# Cocoa View Template

Tags: cocoa, view, xib

In IB, there is a Cocoa View Template that creates a xib without any type of window. I have looked in the docs and can't seem to find how this is useful. You can't just load a xib without a window. Well, you can but it doesn't show anything.

Does anybody know how to use a View Xib without a window? Can it be used as a popupmenu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In IB, there is a Cocoa View Template that creates a xib without any type of window. I have looked in the docs and can't seem to find how this is useful.

A nib with only a window in it would typically be loaded by a [window controller](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindowController_Class/).

A nib with only a view in it would typically be loaded by a [view controller](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSViewController_Class/).

Answer (score 0):

You can place other resources in it such as Bitmaps or infact anyother data types that are supported. You can dynamically load Xib resources at runtime so you could have different Nibs for different languages/functionality.